# Cross posting book reference question

Tags: discussion, questions

On the mathematics site I asked about a book I was looking for:

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2178178/88985

But never got the answer I was looking for ::(

It is for an beginning undergraduate geometry book

Is it okay to ( cross/ also ) post it on this site?

Comment: (I upvoted your meta question because it is useful and clear.  My upvote is not to be taken as agreement that it is okay to post duplicate questions on this site.)

Comment: Also, note that very few users visit Mathematics Educators meta.  Don't be disappointed if you do not get additional responses soon.

Comment: Your post at Mathematics Stack Exchange was very well-received (11 upvotes, no downvotes, 2 answers with no downvotes).  But I don't know if it will be well-received here even if it was not a duplicate.

Comment: I've put a bounty on your Mathematics Stack Exchange question.  Let's see if you get better answers soon.

Comment: I did add a bounty to the post on mathematics stackexchange previously I think that did lead to all the up votes but sadly not to the answer

Comment: It seems that questions similar to yours are welcome at Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/7660/77

Comment: BTW you can include the question in this format to make formatting of your post slightly better: `[Geometry book using Erlangen program](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2178178)` [Geometry book using Erlangen program](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2178178) (And in this way the people reading your question will see the title, so they'll have at least basic idea what the question is about without having to click the link and see the question on the other site.) See also MarkDown help - [links](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links).